# Mainframe Unix Codepage for SYSPRINT or SYSOUT direct display

Tags: unix, cobol, mainframe, codepages

Hello this my first question to StackOverflow, not sure about the forum and topic.

While participating in an Open Mainframe initiative using Visual Studio Code and Putty for Unix I developed a sample program in COBOL showing international sayings (german, english, french, spanish, latin for now). It works fine via batch with JCL to file and being called from REXX. In file I can't see special chars for non-english but I had a lucky punch with a twin-program in PL/1 (doing the same and showing the special chars in REXX).

Now my question: I also tried to call by mvscmd from Unix bash script. It works so far but dont show me the special chars. Ok I have last chance to call mvscmd from Python. Or alternatively I can transfer file from MVS to unix (for any reason then it automatically converts and I see my special chars contents).
Where is the place to handle it? Cobol? (as I said, for any reason PL/1 can do. I only use standard put edit in PL/1 vs display in Cobol). Converting the Sysprint/Sysout?
Any specialist can help me?

Comment: Can you please show sample code (COBOL, REXX, shell script) and JCL? Please edit your question and insert formatted as code sample, not as image.

Comment: "I can't see special chars" - what do you use to view your output? How is the output meant to be encoded?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and sorry for late replay. Well the whole code is a little bit much but I guess my problem is the following - MVSCMD direct coded in the shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
parm='Z08800.FYD.DATA'
#echo "arg1=>"$1"<"
[ ! -z "$1" ] && parm=$parm","$1
#echo "arg2=>"$2"<"
[ ! -z "$2" ] && parm=$parm","$2
#echo "parm=>"$parm"<"

mvscmd --pgm=saycob --args=$parm \
    --steplib='z08800.fyd.load' \
    --sysin=dummy \
    --sysout=*
```

I have some more shell script but this is the main. I directly put it to sysout (its the COBOL diplay. I can use fixed string or my saying read from MVS file). When using PL/1 program the last file is then sysprint because PL/1 makes it by PUT EDIT.

I assume my codepage is pretty wrong. But I dont know how to repair. I used some settings in the shell but LANG remains on C ??? By the way this Unix seems to be quite old and I only have the chance to use it until August.
My main interest is to use the program on Mainframe and in JCL and/or REXX.
But they gave us chance with this embedded Unix (?) also so I wanted to try.
Direct Sysout from COBOL program to Unix terminal.

I meant when executing the program on the Mainframe and then watching the result file in ISPF (old stuff) editor by PF3 I can see German and Spanish and French special characters. So they are there seems, produced by COBOL and PL/1.

When transfering the MVS file (kind of PDS) into the UNIX by MVSCMD, it is also fine (special chars) but thats not what I wanted.

I tried to use Python instead flat shell but its going even worse. I cannot direct the Sysout to terminal, all what is Python able to call is on the Mainframe and with the MVS filesystem. So I have to transfer it after. It is to much overhead in my eyes when call say 7 sayings and I want them to be displayed in the Unix terminal lol.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my REXX that is doing the trick

```
/* rexx */
ARG PARM1 PARM2

PARAMETER = '/Z08800.FYD.DATA'

If Length(PARM1) > 0
   Then PARAMETER = PARAMETER","PARM1
If Length(PARM2) > 0
   Then PARAMETER = PARAMETER","PARM2
PARAMETER = "'"PARAMETER"'"

Address TSO "Alloc File(sysprint) Dataset(*)"
Address TSO "Alloc File(sysin) Dummy"

Address TSO "Call fyd.load(saypli)" PARAMETER

Address TSO "Free  File(sysprint)"
Address TSO "Free  File(sysin)"
```

It is now the other Load, the PL/1 - but the COBOL does the same with Sysout instead of Sysprint.

It is shown in my REXX terminal that is also called by ISPF and then 3.4 in the edit panel. The program has no manual input but reads file. And yes, the sayings are not allocated here, I read them by dynamic allocation but it doesnt matter from where my strings come to the DISPLAY / PUT EDIT

Answer (score 0):

And this now JCL. OK works little different, it stores to PDS member

```
//SAYCOB JOB
//COBCLG  EXEC IGYWCLG,
//             PARM.GO='Z08800.FYD.DATA'
//         SET MBR=SAYCOB
//COBOL.SYSIN  DD DSN=&SYSUID..FYD.SOURCE(&MBR),DISP=SHR
//LKED.SYSLMOD DD DSN=&SYSUID..FYD.LOAD(&MBR),DISP=SHR
//GO.SYSOUT    DD SYSOUT=*
//*-------------------------------------------------------------
//*
//*-------------------------------------------------------------
//SAYCOB  EXEC PGM=&MBR,PARM='Z08800.FYD.DATA,001,007'
//STEPLIB   DD DSN=&SYSUID..FYD.LOAD,DISP=SHR
//SYSOUT    DD DSN=&SYSUID..FYD.OUTPUT(&MBR),DISP=SHR
//*-------------------------------------------------------------
//LIST    EXEC PGM=LINE80,PARM='/80'
//STEPLIB   DD DSN=&SYSUID..FYD.LOAD,DISP=SHR
//SYSIN     DD DSN=&SYSUID..FYD.OUTPUT(&MBR),DISP=SHR
//SYSPRINT  DD SYSOUT=*
//
```

Here in the parameter I give them the library to my sayings and then I allocate by PL/1 or COBOL. I can of course show, but its a little bit much, about 200 lines... The problem is not MVS I guess but the Unix codepage.